# Dictionary storage and retrieval

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> qData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   qData.Add("businessName",Request.QueryString["businessName"]);
}
protected void craCHeck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string value = "";
   value = qData["businessName"];
}
```

If i don't comment the `qData.Add` line, it says the key has already been added. If I do comment it, it says the key was not found.... very confused and frustrated, no idea what I'm doing wrong. :/

Comment: Is this all the code you have? We seem to be missing some pieces of the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the key already exists in the dictionary:

```
if(qData.ContainsKey("businessName")) 
     qData["businessName"] = Request.QueryString["businessName"];
else 
     qData.Add("businessName", Request.QueryString["businessName"]);
```

`Add` method doesn't *add or update* a key-value pair, but it just
adds it. Otherwise, if the key is already present in the given
dictionary, you need to use the indexer as shown in the above code
sample.

Or even better than that. Check what [MSDN states](http://%3E%20%60Add%60%20method%20doesn't%20*add%20or%20update*%20a%20key-value%20pair,%20but%20it%20just%20%3E%20adds%20it.%20Otherwise,%20if%20the%20key%20is%20already%20present%20in%20the%20given%20%3E%20dictionary,%20you%20need%20to%20use%20the%20indexer%20as%20shown%20in%20the%20above%20code%20%3E%20sample.) about the generic dictionary indexer:

> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is
>   not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set
>   operation creates a new element with the specified key.

Thus, you can also simplify your code as follows:

```
// No need of using Add() or the indexer. You can 
// just use the indexer instead in either case:
qData["businessName"] = Request.QueryString["businessName"];
```

Comment: Is there any reason to check if the key exists?  Why not just use the `qData["businessName"] = ...` line by itself?  The indexer will add it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

the key might already exsists , depending on the calling context 
easiest thing to do is to check if the key exists before you add it

```
if (!qData.ContainsKey(key)) 
{
     qData.Add("businessName",Request.QueryString["businessName"]);
}
```

and when you read from the dictionary , check the key is there

```
if (qData.ContainsKey(key)) 
{
      value = qData["businessName"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   qData["businessName"] = Request.QueryString["businessName"]);
}
protected void craCHeck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string value = "";
   qData.TryGetValue("businessName", out value))
}
```

But a fixed key of "businessName" just makes not sense to me

```
string queryString = string.empty; 
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   queryString = Request.QueryString["businessName"]);
}
protected void craCHeck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string value = queryString;
}
```